# nnoremap <C-k> <C-w>k in vimrc

Tags: vim

I have the following line in my .vimrc.

```
nnoremap <C-h> <C-w>h
nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j
nnoremap <C-k> <C-w>k
nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>l
```

The first two lines lets me toggle between top window and bottom window in split mode of vim.
What does the other two keys do?

```
<C-k> and <C-l>
```

I have tried them.It doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: `:h CTRL_W_h` or `:h CTRL_W_j` or `:h CTRL_W_k` or `:h CTRL_W_l`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`h` (left), `j` (down), `k` (up), `l` (right) are the navigation keys. You are combining them with `<C-w>` to avoid another key press.

So, if you have four windows open, say you do:

```
vim a
:vsp b
:new c
 do a `<C-w> l` and then again a `:new d`
```

Now, you can navigate around using the key mappings that you have mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

These mappings are added to make navigation between splits easier.
They will work if you split the windows vertically. Open the files with
 `vim -O file1 file2 ...` for vertical split and then try the commands.

So with your mappings,

Vertical Split: `vim -O file1 file2 ...`

```
<C-h>  - Move to the left split
<C-l>  - Move to the right split
```

---

Horizontal Split:  `vim -o file1 file2 ...`

```
<C-j>  - Move to the split below
<C-k>  - Move to the split above
```